# Await in TestCafe

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have been having some problems with understanding when/how `await` is used and required in TestCafé.

Why is does this function require an `await` on the first line?

```
async getGroupCount(groupName) {
  const groupFilterLinkText = await this.groupFilterLink.withText(groupName).textContent;
  const openInd = groupFilterLinkText.indexOf('(');
  const closeInd = groupFilterLinkText.indexOf(')');
  const count = parseInt(groupFilterLinkText.slice(openInd + 1, closeInd), 10);
  return count;
}
```

I later found in the doc that it says "Note that these methods and property getters are asynchronous, so use await to obtain an element's property." However, I'm using the function I wrote in a pretty synchronous way so this took me completely by surprise. I have ensured that the page is in the state that I want it to be in, and I just want to parse a string, but the test errors on line 2 of this function without the `async`/`await`.

Related to this, this is an example test case that calls that function:

```
test('Verify an account owner can create a single user', async (t) => {
  const userName = 'Single User';
  const userEmail = 'singleuser@wistia.com';
  const origUserCount = await usersPage.getGroupCount('All Users');

  await t
    .click(usersPage.addUserButton);

  await waitForReact();

  await t
    .typeText(usersPage.addUserModal.nameInput, userName)
    .typeText(usersPage.addUserModal.emailInput, userEmail)
    .expect(usersPage.addUserModal.saveButton.hasAttribute('disabled')).notOk()
    .click(usersPage.addUserModal.saveButton)
    .expect(usersPage.userCard.withText(userName).exists).ok({ timeout: 10000 });

  const newUserCount = await usersPage.getGroupCount('All Users');

  await t
    .expect(newUserCount).eql(origUserCount + 1);
});
```

Originally, I had the last few lines of the test looking like this:

```
await t
  ...
  .click(usersPage.addUserModal.saveButton)
  .expect(usersPage.userCard.withText(userName).exists).ok({ timeout: 10000 })
  .expect(await usersPage.getGroupCount('All Users')).eql(origUserCount + 1);
```

That is, it was included in one function chain for the entire test. This failed because the value of `await usersPage.getGroupCount('All Users')` was still returning the original value instead of getting updated. I don't understand why I need to separate that out into its own call to the function. Why is that `getGroupCount` being evaluated seemingly at the beginning of the test rather than when the test reaches that line of code? It doesn't seem to be behaving asynchronously in the way that I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentations (https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/built-in-waiting-mechanisms.html), it seems like you don't have to separate it out into it's own call but you'll have to shift the await to the beginning of the chain?

So for example, instead of:

```
<something>
  .click(usersPage.addUserModal.saveButton)
  .expect(usersPage.userCard.withText(userName).exists).ok({ timeout: 10000 })
  .expect(await usersPage.getGroupCount('All Users')).eql(origUserCount + 1);
```

You can do:

```
await <something>
  .click(usersPage.addUserModal.saveButton)
  .expect(usersPage.userCard.withText(userName).exists).ok({ timeout: 10000 })
  .expect(usersPage.getGroupCount('All Users')).eql(origUserCount + 1);
```

Comment: Sorry that wasn't more clear, the await is in the beginning of the chain. I tried to shorten the chain for clarity, but its original state was:

     await t
      .typeText(usersPage.addUserModal.nameInput, userName)
      .typeText(usersPage.addUserModal.emailInput, userEmail)
      .expect(usersPage.addUserModal.saveButton.hasAttribute('disabled')).notOk()
      .click(usersPage.addUserModal.saveButton)
      .expect(usersPage.userCard.withText(userName).exists).ok({ timeout: 10000 })
      .expect(await usersPage.getGroupCount('All Users')).eql(origUserCount + 1);

Comment: Ah ok, but if you have await at the beginning of the chain, I think you can omit the await in the .expect() chain, no? Not sure if it'll change anything but could give it a quick go.

Comment: 1) Attempted to run assertions on a Promise object. Did you forget to await it? If not, pass "{ allowUnawaitedPromise: true }"
      to the assertion options.

       > 144 |    .expect(usersPage.getGroupCount('All Users')).eql(origUserCount + (userEmails.length - 1));
         145 |});

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry about that, I didn't understand it enough. Looking deeper into it, I came across this note:
"You cannot pass a regular promise to the expect method unless the options.allowUnawaitedPromise option is enabled.".
This section https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/#optionsallowunawaitedpromise explains about some of the limitations and what to do for promises that aren't associated with the selectors or client functions. I don't know if you've already tried it, but if not, perhaps it might help.